# "get_current_user_id()" strict comparison with number fails

Tags: php, wordpress, comparison-operators

I've got a technical question to which I would like to have insights more than a solution.

I hooked a custom function to 'template_include' filter in WordPress functions.php as below to work on a page without it being watchable by anyone else.

```
function template_redirect( $template ) {
    if ( $template === locate_template('single-ressource.php') && get_current_user_id() === 11 ) { 
        return $new_template = locate_template( array( 'single.php' ) );
    }
    return $template;
};
add_filter( 'template_include', 'template_redirect', 99 );
```

So if anyone who's not logged into my account go to a 'ressource' custom post type page, they see it with the standard single.php layout and not with the single-ressource.php layout.

The thing is, it doesn't work as is. I have to change the `11` integer in the strict comparison to `'11'` string to make it <strike>work</strike> (**see edit**), as below.

```
function template_redirect( $template ) {
    if ( $template === locate_template('single-ressource.php') && get_current_user_id() === '11' ) { 
        return $new_template = locate_template( array( 'single.php' ) );
    }
    return $template;
};
add_filter( 'template_include', 'template_redirect', 99 );
```

I went to see the official documentation for the [get_current_user_id()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/) function and it seems that they use type casting to return either an integer or `0`.

Furthermore, when I do a `var_dump(get_current_user_id())` on my front-end, it returns `int(11)`.

Anyone has an idea about why the <strike>second code works</strike> (**see edit**) and not the first one?

**Edit**

As @Bazaim pointed it out, I was just confused about the logic involved.

With the second code, the actual "single-ressource.php" I wanted to hide wasn't hidden to anyone because the logic behind the condition passed was flawed. I was redirecting only users with a `user_id` equal to a string `'11'` which is no one because `user_id` are integers.

The code below works perfectly.

```
function template_redirect( $template ) {
    if ( $template === locate_template('single-ressource.php') && get_current_user_id() !== 11 ) { 
        return $new_template = locate_template( array( 'single.php' ) );
    }
    return $template;
};
add_filter( 'template_include', 'template_redirect', 99 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user_id is 11 ?

You require to see `single.php` :

- `$template` to be `'single-ressource.php'` : right
- `get_current_user_id()` to be `11` : wrong, you want the id not to be `11`

Comment: Indeed! Thank you for pointing it out to me, I must have been very confused.

Comment: I can't see this, why does the OP's second example work then?

Comment: Because I am basically asking to hide the proper template to anyone who's logged in with a user_id equal to a string '11', which is everyone because user_id are integers. 

Which means the second example doesn't really work because everyone can see the page with the template I'm working on, and  not the standard I wanted to redirect to.